# simple html/css class riddle

Tags: jquery, html, css

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cneeds/FBvkQ/) fiddle, click the Policies button, click the New policy button and, according to the second line of this html (near the bottom of the code)

```
<fieldset id="NewpolicyOverlay" class="menuAbuttons">
  <p><a href="#" class="menuA menuA-open returnBttn" name="level02" title="Create a new policy"><span>New policy</span></a></p>
  <a href="#" id="NewPolicy" class="menuA menuA-open overlayBttnA" name="NewPolicy"><span>Policy</span></a>
  <a href="#" id="Sections" class="menuA overlayBttnA" name="Sections"><span>Sections</span></a>
  <a href="#" id="Transaction" class="menuA overlayBttnA" name="Transaction"><span>Transaction</span></a>
  <a href="#" id="NewPolicySubmit" class="menuB overlayBttnA" name="NewPolicySubmit"><span>Submit</span></a>
</fieldset>
```

the New policy button should display as 'open' (i.e. look the same as the Policy button below it). Even when I inspect the element with FF it doesn't have the menuA-open class. But the code above clearly says it should. It gets the other two classes: menuA and returnBttn, but not the menuA-open class.

In simple terms, the New policy button should be grey with a blue border after it's been clicked.

Can anyone please solve this riddle?

Thank you

Chris

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Can you clarify your question by making it specific towards functionality as opposed to class names?

Comment: You'll find it easier to get a good answer if you can make the example HTML,CSS and JS as simple as possible while still reproducing the problem - there seems to be quite a bit that's unrelated there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove the class `menuA` from that element when you click "Policies". You should alter your selector so as to only remove that class from `<a>` elements from the top bar (I assume you want that): http://jsfiddle.net/FBvkQ/1/.

```
$(".menuA").click(function() {
    // ...
    $('#menudiv > .menuA') // ...
```

Comment: Cool, pimvdb, I hope that wasn't too much of a headache. The lesson I've learnt here is to review previous code even though it's (assumed to be) working. Thank you for your help! The correct solution for my logic was to change the name property in the New policy anchor tag (in the snippet) to "NewpolicyOverlay" as it is not part of the level structure. Chris